# how to sum the amount of cells with the same number in a column - Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

My english isn't that good, I hope you understand what I wan't to accomplish

I have a column (A) with different zip codes ( total of 3583 rows). I need a formula/function to go through each cell and the come up with sum of how many instances (column B) there are of the same zip code (column C).There are probably more than hundred different zip codes so I can't do it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot Tables are an easy way to accomplish that. They allow for the very operation you have in mind.
You can create a table that has your zip codes in the first column and the "amount of" each zip code in the next column. It is literally just a couple of clicks.
If you are not familiar with the basics of Pivot Tables, check this out:
https://www.google.com/#q=excel+pivot+table+basics